# How to find the total number of addressable_load event count in between first_login and game_launch event group by user_pseudo_id in big query

Tags: google-bigquery

[image]

In BigQuery, I'm trying to find  total number of addressable_load eventcount  in between first login and game_launch event group by `user_pseudo_id`.

I got the all events on particular day with following query

```
SELECT 
       user_pseudo_id,user_id,event_name,
       Datetime(timestamp_micros(event_timestamp),"UCT") as date_time ,
       MIN(CASE WHEN event_name = 'first_open' THEN
                     Datetime(timestamp_micros(event_timestamp),"UCT") 
              END) as app_open_date,
       MAX(CASE WHEN event_name = 'app_remove' THEN
                     Datetime(timestamp_micros(event_timestamp),"UCT")
              END) as app_remove_date
FROM `aaa-96dd2.analytics_272019935.events_*`
WHERE event_date="20230405"
GROUP BY user_pseudo_id, event_name,event_timestamp, user_id
ORDER BY event_timestamp;
```

Now I need the total number of addressable load count  in between first login and app launch event group by user_pseudo_id in big query.

In Big Query, I'm trying to find  total number of addressable_load eventcount  in between first login and game_launch event group by user_pseudo_id in big query.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider that a user can login several times. Here a solution with windows function.

```sql
WITH
tbl as (
SELECT 
       user_pseudo_id,user_id,event_name,
       Datetime(timestamp_micros(event_timestamp),"UCT") as date_time ,
       event_name = 'first_open' as app_open,
       event_name = 'app_remove' as app_remove,
       event_name = 'login' as login,
       event_name = 'game_launch ' as game_launch,
FROM `aaa-96dd2.analytics_272019935.events_*`
WHERE event_date="20230405"
GROUP BY user_pseudo_id, event_name,event_timestamp, user_id
ORDER BY event_timestamp;
),
helper as (
Select *,
countif(login) over cts as login_counter,
countif(game_launch) over cts as game_launch_counter,
if(login, date_time, null) as login_time,

from tbl
window cts as (partition by user_pseudo_id order by date_time rows between unbounded preceding and current row)
)

Select user_pseudo_id, login_counter, game_launch_counter,
min(login_time) as login_time,
max(date_time) as date_time_max, 
count(1) as steps_count,
countif(event_name = "loading_process") as steps_loading_process,
string_agg(event_name) as event_names,

from helper
group by 1,2,3
#having min(login_time) is not null # should only keep items between login and launch
```